# '04 Echo shock mounts, Type A vs Type B

Tags: toyota, suspension, echo

So I'm noticing quite a bit of rust on my strut and near the mounts, and I was thinking about doing this myself. So when I dig into the service manual, and possibly ordering parts, I found a not so nice problem.

Apparently there are 2 type of strut mount, and when I brought the car in to a dealer, gave them the VIN, they said the system didn't offer to tell them which exact one is needed.

Is there a way to tell which one is which without actually taking the shock out?

[Toyota Parts Direct](http://www.toyotapartsdirect.ca/a/Toyota_2004_Echo1500CC-16-VALVE-DOHC-EFI--MANUAL3-DOOR/_50018_5910166/Front-spring--shock-absorber/481697-4803-112410.html) diagram shows Type A and Type B, and there is a hole near the front bolt, which suggests that it's a Type B. But I would like a second opinion.

Answer (score 1):

The offset of the hole is what's going to tell you which one you have. If you look at the images, Type A offsets towards single bolt (or towards the point), while Type B offsets towards the double bolt (or towards the flat). Type B is within the intersection of the two bolts. If yours doesn't go anywhere near there, you have Type A. You should be able to look at the top of your mount without pulling out the strut to tell this.

[image]